# Cypress + Unable to see the dashboard even after cy.request command passes

Tags: cypress

I am basically new to Cypress and wanted to implement the login page using cy.request command inorder
to bypass the UI. My cy.request() passes with 200 response code. However i am not able to visit the dashboard page after successful login. Kindly guide me  through this

Below is the code

```
Cypress.Commands.add('loginByJSON', (username, password) => {

 return cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'My website login url',
  body: {
    "username" : username,
    "password" : password,
  }
}).then((resp)=> {
    expect(resp.status).to.eq(200)
})

})
```

Inside the test page

```
describe('Sign In Page', function () {

 it('OnSuccessful Login', function () {

    cy.loginByJSON("test@gmail.com","test@1234");
    cy.visit('http://test-apac.appspot.com/#/dashboard')
    cy.title().should("eq","Dashboard")
})
})
```

The Assert statement passes further while visiting the dashboard page it again open the login page, even after successful login
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: why not to go to the login page (in the test) and then fill the inputs and press login button... and your application should redirect him to the dashboard page

Comment: i thought this was a better approach, since then i do not need to open the login page for every test. Also i did try your approach of filling inputs and redirecting to dashboard but the website takes some time to load, and before it loads the assert statements next to it start executing and fail. If i put wait,it works in some scenarios but not all the time.

Comment: it sounds ok, with the wait time .. it is similar to the real app. you must wait for the server response.. or make an initial state